# C# Initialize Dictionary Containing Dynamic Array of Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dictionary, dynamic

As you can see I am trying to Initialize a Dictionary Containing a Dynamic Array of Dynamic Arrays. Can someone give me a cleaner way of doing this? There must be a way to do this with a for loop.

```
// Sizes: 20X, 40X, W, M, WM, Other
sizesDict.Add(eDate, new dynamic[6] { // Date, Size
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    },
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    },
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    },
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    },
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    },
    new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString() }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you even using `dynamic`? You could create strong types for this and add type safety to your code. Also you are adding the same values 2x in each array AND each array is an exact duplicate of the one before it (they are all the same). Finally why are you using lists for single values, why not just use `string` or `decimal` instead of `List<string>` and `List<decimal>`?

Comment: Are the inner-most dynamic arrays always going to be initialized with the same values, like you show?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're using dynamics, but you could do it like this:

Create a function to create one of your inner-most dynamic arrays:

```
private static dynamic[] GetDataArray(
    decimal rangeMax,
    decimal rangeMin,
    string originMax,
    string originMin,
    string destMax,
    string destMin)
{
    return new dynamic[6] { // Data
        /* RangeMax */
        new List<decimal> { rangeMax },
        /* RangeMin */
        new List<decimal> { rangeMin },
        /* OriginMax */
        new List<string>  { originMax },
        /* OriginMin */
        new List<string>  { originMin },
        /* DestinationMax */
        new List<string>  { destMax },
        /* DestinationMin */
        new List<string>  { destMin }
    };
}
```

Then call that function 6 times adding each dynamic array to your outer-most dynamic array.  And finally, add that array to your dictionary.

```
dynamic[] allData = new dynamic[6];
for (int i = 0; i < allData.Length; i++)
{
    allData[i] = GetDataArray(
        r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total,
        r.rateEvalDLoc.rateEvalOLoc.charge.Total,
        r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString(),
        r.rateEvalDLoc.originLoc.LocationName.ToString(),
        r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString(),
        r.destinationLoc.LocationName.ToString());
}

sizesDict.Add(eDate, allData);
```

If RangeMax is always going to be equal to RangeMin, and OriginMax == OriginMin, and DestinationMax == DestinationMin you could simplify the function to only have 3 arguments.  Also if all of the inner-most dynamic arrays are going to have the same contents you could greatly simplify it even further.